# How to start an application MarkLogic using bash command

Tags: bash, centos

I am using Docker to install an application MarkLogic and deploy some files in the installed application. The docker image is hosted on a centOS7 machine.
I am using this bash command to start the Marklogic inside the container which is returning me an error -

Command

```
service /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start
```

Error

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start etc-init.d-MarkLogic.mount
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

What would be the correct bash command to start the application.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read and follow its instructions?

https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-docker/blob/master/README.md

Once inside container

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/procedures#id_84772